# I am trying to make a GUI in Java.I created the frame, but the panel doesn't show up. What is wrong?

Tags: java, swing

When everything was in one class, it was working. I tried to separate them to obtain a more "structured" code, but now only the frame shows up.

My Main-class:

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicInterface gameInterface;
        gameInterface = new GraphicInterface();
   }
}
```

GraphicInterface-class:

```
public class GraphicInterface {
    public GraphicInterface() {
        GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame();
        MainPanel menuPanel = new MainPanel();
        gameFrame.addPanel(menuPanel);
        menuPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

GameFrame-class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    public GameFrame() {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("Games");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        gameFrame.setSize(905, 700);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addPanel(JPanel menuPanel) {
        this.add(menuPanel);
    }
}
```

MainPanel-class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 905, 700);
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(243, 207, 252));
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer: dont go for "trial" and "error" when learning Swing. Read good existing tutorials. There are too many things that can go wrong when you just "try" things yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intend to use a `GameFrame` object as your `JFrame`, but `GameFrame` creates a brand new other frame for no reason.
So just avoid this and use only your `GameFrame` :

```
public GameFrame() {
    super("Games");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setSize(905, 700);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

In the same way , you want to use a `MainPanel` object as a container, but it creates a new `JPanel` which will be discarded without being used at all, so as above :

```
public MainPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0, 0, 905, 700);
    setBackground(new Color(243, 207, 252));
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: He is 100% right you should maybe consider looking into the way "extends" works..